# SMS notification of emails received at Gmail not working?

Tags: email, notifications, google-apps-script, gmail

You must be aware on this Google scripted app at the following link which lets you receive SMS notification of emails arrived at  your Gmail address.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms

I tried it; it worked in the beginning and sent me a few notifications but later on it stopped working, I followed the same process(copying and pasting the code in google doc, script editor) again and it then started working, but now it has totally stopped working. I redid the same process again but to no use. It is not sending me any notifications at all.
Please help

Comment: What do the execution logs show? Else, you could surround the block of code with a try/catch.

Comment: You really need to show your code and demonstrate what is/is not happening. However, if you are expecting many mails to be caught by triggered script you may be exceeding time limit as the SMS is a fairly slow op CalendarEvent.addSmsReminder([0]) [2.69 seconds]